# Screen flashing, application bar disappearing, mouse freezes in Gnome

Tags: gnome

I recently installed Ubuntu 11 64 bit server on my Power Edge 1650.  When Gnome loads, I receive no flickering of any sort -- everything looks beautiful.  I can login just fine.

However, after the desktop loads, the application bar disappears and I can't click anything.  It remains gone, though I can move the mouse.  It flashes up for a second, until I move the mouse, and then the process repeats over again -- with everything disappearing.  I can't use commands until the application appears.  For instance, Ctrl+Alt+F1 won't work until the application bar reappears.

All software is brand new out of the box, with default configurations.  It feels like a video card configuration, but this isn't just some desktop computer I've loaded ubuntu on -- it's a popular server-class blade, so I'm not sure why this would be happening?

This is my first experience with Gnome and Ubuntu (and linux) -- I have no experience, and my searches are of little help.  Any help is appreciated.

As another note, I received a message saying something along the lines of **hardware not supported for unity** the first time I loaded the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to turn fix this issue by logging in to the classic Ubuntu environment after I selected my user name.  The flashing and issues went away.